# How can I parse Javascript using Xpath?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to parse the html pages using php xpath, there are some data that are inserted into html through javascript, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
   var insertName = function() {                
       var firstName = 'Hi SomeUserName';
       $('#welcomeMessage').html(firstName)
   }
</script>
<h1 id="welcomeMessage"></h1>
```

I want to extract the data 'hi SomeUserName' alone.

Is it possible to do this in php xpath? or is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jParser](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/jparser/index.html) - A JavaScript parsing library for PHP for parsing JavaScript code inside `<script>` tag. And to get `<script>` tag, [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or any other HTML parser can be used.

Comment: thanks for the information!, i just tried jparser, its first converting javascript to xml and i have to parse the xml again, though it gives a way to parse javascript its making the job more cumbersome in think, i am now using the normal string functions of php to get the required text.